# error while using JSON.parse() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have following data in JSON format and I want to parse in in JavaScript.

```
{"id":"897868990272958","posts":{"data":[{"id":"897868990272958_965738636819326","message":"As you are now aware, Federal elections have to be financed by personal donations only. To support my campaign, there is still tickets for my cocktail of Aug.27. at Balmoral's Community center. A 75% tax credit will be given for the net value of the ticket after expenses (+/- 33,75$ back into your pockets).\n\nComme vous le savez, les élections fédérales ne sont financées que par des dons personnels. Afin d'encourager ma campagne, il reste toujours des billets pour le cocktail du 27 août au centre communautaire de Balmoral. Un crédit d'impôt de 75% vous sera retourné sur la valeur net du billet après dépenses (+/- 33,75$ de retour dans vos poches).\n\nTo reserve tickets/pour réserver des billets: 753-6121.","comments":{"data":[{"id":"965738636819326_966081753451681","message":"je t'encourage mon rene mes indisponible ce soir"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"after":"MQ==","before":"MQ=="}}}},{"id":"897868990272958_965083470218176","message":"Hier, Haut-Madawaska !\n\nVisite d'entreprises et quelques poignées de mains à Clair et Baker Brook.  Une visite éclaire à Saint-Hilaire et Edmundston puis, en soirée, rencontre avec le conseil municipal du Lac Baker.  Le Haut-Madawaska est un exemple d'entrepreneurship  et d'esprit d'initiative.  Le chômage y est à zéro et on manque de travailleurs.   Pas besoin d'envier la Beauce.  À preuve, cette Coopérative qui vient de naitre à Clair et dont l'objectif ultime est de créer de l'emploi à partir de nos ressources à portée de main, et de miser sur la transformation.  Bravo à tous ces convaincus et bénévoles qui ne jurent que par le mouvement coopératif et l'esprit communautaire.\n\nBravo aussi au conseil municipal et au maire suppléant du Lac Baker pour leur dévouement et l'énergie qu'ils mettent à protéger et développer ce bijoux de village.\n\nÀ entendre les gens que nous croisons, dans la rue ou dans les usines, nous recevons une oreille très attentive au Plan des libéraux, relativement à la classe moyenne.  Il ne fait aucun doute, le vent tourne !"},{"id":"897868990272958_962429560483567","message":"Venez me rencontrer pour un cocktail !!!\nPour réserver votre billet, communiquez avec nous au quartier général libéral au 753-6121 (15 rue water, Campbellton NB)\n****************************************\nCome and meet me for a cocktail !!!\nTo reserve your tickets, please contact us at the liberal campaign office at 753-6121 (15 Water street, Campbellton NB)"},{"id":"897868990272958_961763833883473","message":"Hier, 18 août, visite de deux conseils municipaux coup sur coup !\n\nD'abord Balmoral. Comme d'autres municipalités de taille équivalente que j'ai déjà rencontrées, un conseil maitrisant ses dossiers avec des projets responsables et raisonnables à portée de réalisation. Il ne manque que la collaboration du fédéral qui n'est que trop absent. Bravo pour ce dynamisme.\n\nEnsuite Dalhousie. Comment ne pas lever son chapeau au maire Tremblay et ses conseillers et conseillères. Ils se battent pour notre petite ville du Restigouche-Est qui a subi des pertes de revenus «drastiques» suivant la fermeture du moulin et celle du plan thermique d'ÉNB. They are facing big challenges and they will have difficult decisions to take. We know the town's council will take those decisions in the best interest of it's community in mind. I will be there with an attentive ear to support their projets."},{"id":"897868990272958_961114093948447","message":"Aujourd'hui, Saint-Léonard au Rendez-vous des artistes !\n\nGrosse chaleur d'été, de beaux tableaux, de belles sculptures, des artistes extraordinaires et des gens qui nous laissent toujours entendre que... le vent tourne ! Je suis revenu à la maison avec ce tableau de circonstance en cette fin de semaine du 15 août. Merci à l'artiste-peintre Péruse. Surtout, toutes nos félicitations aux bénévoles qui ont encore fait un succès de ce rendez-vous des artistes.\n\nWarm day at «Le rendez-vous des artistes\". We saw beautiful paintings, sculpturs, and talked with interesting artists. And how pleasant it was to meet people. They surely let us know that the tide is turning ! I came back home with this beautiful painting right on the point for the ending weekend of the Acadian day. Thanks to artist-painter Péruse. Also, congratulations to all volunteers that made this artists gathering a success."}],"paging":{"previous":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/897868990272958/posts?limit=5&fields=comments.limit%2815%29%7Bcomments%7Bmessage%7D,message%7D,message&since=1440606601&__paging_token=enc_AdD9KfoIkGsvwvKGKPHUvyEPbhuF2RoK63BKHTPw7tovNNMLZAZApH668RXKwpdMnnp7D6psZAc7wZAh0DlYIFoNPsjXjzfML0qyh30Oasasv9pyZAAZDZD&__previous=1","next":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/897868990272958/posts?limit=5&fields=comments.limit%2815%29%7Bcomments%7Bmessage%7D,message%7D,message&until=1439765409&__paging_token=enc_AdDayGW6NPPTZA7gGT2HgRGZAVqinlc7ijLdPwYbZBexBpuBejfIzGdM42uW1GbO8epju5j8dDNv8qJ1lY8SMLZBZBQ3J0cIywdzQclw8KmqXv8HWlgZDZD"}}}
```

When I use the console of Google Chrome to do that it gives me an error. I want to write following lines:

```
var json = MY_DATA;
JSON.parse(json);
```

But when I want to assign my data to `json` the console gives me following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier(…)
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your JSON is already parsed to an object. You then try to parse it again and it is confused.

This is a pretty common mistake.

Some functionalities in jQuery automatically parse JSON and don't need to be explicitly told to.

Comment: OK! then my definition of parsing is wrong maybe!! Actually, what I need is that I want to have an object let's say an array contains all the (variable, value) pair in my JSON data. Is that possible in JavaScript?

Comment: How can create such an object then? I am so sorry but I honestly didn't get why I got the error!!? I only have a string in JSON format (the one I mentioned in my question) - How can I make an object contains (varriable, value) pair of that string? Should I parse the string by myself or there is already library in JavaScript to do that for me?

Answer (score 2):

@Adosi has already answered this correctly but I was adding an example so I'll include it anyway as it's too long for a comment. Add this to your code and open up your browser's console.

```javascript
console.clear();

// your original data
var json = MY_DATA;
console.info("var json is a", typeof json);
console.log('json.id:', json.id); 

// when json is stored as a string, it needs to be parsed.
// let's convert it back into a string and see what happens
var json_needing_parsing = JSON.stringify(json)
console.info("var json_needing_parsing is a", typeof json_needing_parsing);
console.log('json_needing_parsing.id:', json_needing_parsing.id); //undefined

// That didn't work. Let's parse it.
var json_parsed = JSON.parse(json_needing_parsing);
console.info("var json_parsed is a", typeof json_parsed);
console.log("json_parsed.id:", json_parsed.id);
```

Here it is in action. http://jsfiddle.net/qn9xkt7c/ (because the Stack Snippet editor was cross at me for the giant json object)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But my problem is that I cannot assign the string which I mentioned in my question to the variable ``json``... The browser gives me an error (the one I mentioned in my question) - My problem is that I cannot assign my value to the ``json`` variable. Why is it happening?

Comment: @Suo6613 make a Stack Snippet or JSFiddle demonstrating the problem? Just added a link to a JSFiddle with it working so perhaps there's something else going on with your code?

Comment: OW! in the link you provided you have not surrounded the value of MY_DATA with a double-quote!! why? When I put the data in double-quote it gives me an error!! shouldn't I put the json format in a double-quote?!

Comment: "shouldn't I put the json format in a double-quote?!" No. Why not make this easier and post what you've got?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know how to use the things you suggested. But I have already posted everything in my question! just open console of Google Chrome. Write ``var json = "MY_DATA";``. once you enter it gives you the error ``Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier(…)``. But if I write ``var json = MY_DATA;`` it does not give me any error!

Comment: By adding quotes around `MY_DATA`, `var json = "MY_DATA";` is setting the variable `json` to be equal to the text string `"MY_DATA"`, not whatever was stored in the variable `MY_DATA`. Put that into your console and then add `console.log( typeof json ); console.log( json.split('_') );` and you'll see it's a string.

Comment: For what it's worth, you would have had yout answer close-to-immediately had you put it into a JSFiddle because many folks would have spotted your quote problem immediately. It's very easy to do and if you're not familiar with it, decide to take 5 minutes to become familiar with it! It'll pay you back quickly: http://jsfiddle.net/. Added bonus: often when trying to reduce your problem to fit into a fiddle for others, you take away enough extraneous gunk that you find it yourself. I can't count how many *unposted* SO questions I've had because I saw the problem while creating the jsfiddle.